# How can adjective be a object of preposition?

Tags: grammar, syntax

A student asked the teacher.

"How can adjective be a object of preposition? Such as 'for sure', 'in general'."

The three teachers' answers to this are as follows.

teacher A: "You can understand it as form 'being' omitted, such as 'for (being) sure'."

teacher B: "You can understand it as form 'thing' omitted, such as 'for sure (thing)'."

teacher C: "It's just idiom. Suck it up."

Which answer do you think makes sense?

Comment: C is the closest. These are prep+adj **idioms**.

Answer (score 2):

The OED, s.v, **for** (*prep.*, *conj.*), sense 19, says

> **a**. In the character of, in the light of, as equivalent to; esp. to
> introduce the complement after verbs of incomplete predication, e.g.
> *to have, hold*, etc. (see those verbs), where *as* or *as being* may
> generally be substituted. ...

> **b**. So with an adjective, as in ***to take for granted, to leave for dead,*** etc. ***for certain, for sure, †for wiss***, see those adjectives

So the OED accepts it as a construction that "for" occurs in, but I would say that it is obsolete except for a limited set of words following (also *for free*), and should be treated as an idiom.

Likewise s.v. **in**, *prep*:

> **36**. With a substantive (or adj.), forming an *adv.phr.*, e.g. *in charity, in duty, in honour; in right; in common, in general, in
> especial; in fact, in (all) probability, in truth, in faith; in
> conclusion, in fine; in haste; in any case, in every way; in (all) the
> world*. See the *ns*.

The OED doesn't distinguish nouns from adjectives in this construction, and again I would suggest that there is a limited range of adjectives that occur, so again, it should be treated as an idiom.